# Windows Firewall with secure connection - ipsec

Tags: windows, ipsec

I am trying to set up host based firewall rules with machine authentication to ensure that only certain machines (regardless of IP...in DHCP environment) can access the target machine.  That is, I am using the "Allow the connection if it is secure" feature in the firewall rule and putting the client computer in the "Authorized computers" list. For example, only endpoint1 can access endpoint2 via 445 (SMB). Endpoint1 is the authorized computer and the firewall rule is in place on endpoint2.

While testing this, I ran into a snag that I am hoping the community can help in point me in the right direction.

For some reason I can get one machine (happens to be a 2008r2 server) to connect using this rule, but not another (server 2012 and win8).

When connecting to endpoint2 where the rule is in place to allow endpoint1 and endpoint3 to access endpoint2, endpoint1 will connect fine and endpoint3 will be dropped by the firewall.  I cannot find logging or event logs that would provide any details why.

Surely I am missing some simple prerequisite or something.

Any thoughts on troubleshooting or ideas on prerequisites that are alluding me? Or ideas on what might be missing or disabled/enabled on the machine that works versus the ones that don't?

---

edit: see my comment below for solution.

Comment: This is more of a Super User question

Comment: Disregard the above related to one machine working and the other not.

The answer to the overall problem (red herring above notwithstanding) was that a connection security rule also needed to be in place to request inbound and outbound authentication prior to make the firewall rule that specified computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard the above related to one machine working and the other not. The answer to the overall problem (red herring above notwithstanding) was that a connection security rule also needed to be in place to request inbound and outbound authentication prior to make the firewall rule that specified computers.